# bootstrap-select not working on narrow fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [bootstrap-select.js](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) to enhance a mobile site.

On the page where I'm having the problem, I am already successfully using the plugin to style fields, like this:

```
<div>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.paymentChoices}" styleClass="selectpicker">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Select an Option" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{bea.paymentChoiceItems}" var="selectItem" itemLabel="#{selectItem.label}" itemValue="#{selectItem.value}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</div>
```

The JS I use to apply the selectpicker style is as follows:

```
$(".selectpicker").selectpicker('mobile);
```

However, I have 3 menus that also have the selectpicker class, but who's width are set to 30% of the screen's width - theJS fails to set the selectpicker style on them.

Anyone have any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem found(and solved!):

I had the widths set to 30%, like I mentioned in my question.

I added some media queries to check the screen width, and set the dropdown width accordingly, *without* using percentages, e.g. `width: npx;` not `width: 30%`